# SQL Azure VM (Resource Manager) can't send DBMail (Port 587 blocked)

Tags: sql-server, azure, virtual-machine, azure-sql-database

I created a new VM for SQL Server and trying to setup the dbmail. The smtp server settings are all valid but I can't send emails out. I keep on getting following error:

```
The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. 
(Sending Mail using Account 1 (2016-07-20T09:19:34). 
Exception Message: Could not connect to mail server. (A connection attempt     failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 159.122.224.196:587).
)
```

I tried doing a telnet check on the IP and port no. from my my local machine and SQL Server VM. While the local machine just works fine, the SQL Server VM can't connect to the port.

I also tried to open a port 587 using the link http://michaelsync.net/2015/09/28/where-is-the-endpoint-setting-for-vm-in-new-azure-portal but even after allowing a port 587, I still can't send emails. Any help will be much appreciated.

NOTE: The IP address 159.122.224.196 belongs to sendgrid.

Answer (score 0):

What E-mail (SMTP) server are you using?
Make sure that you're configuring connectivity to it correctly and that the E-mail server is